# Converting datetime format to 12 hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this query

```
select CONVERT(varchar(5), tdate ,108) AS [Time] from table
```

which gives me the time in 24 hour format( military)

I wanted to convert it into a 12 hour format so i tried the query below

```
 select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, tdate, 100),13,2) + ':' 
+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, tdate, 100),16,2) + ''
+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, tdate, 100),18,2) AS T  
from table
```

and i get the 12 hour format but I am just curious if there is a shorter or better way of doing it. any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to convert the current datetime for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 100) AS DateTime_In_12h_Format
```

Instead of getdate() you can put your desired column in a query (such as tdate in your example). If you want JUST the time in 12h and not the date and time use substring/right to separate them. It seems that you already know how to =).

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx) lists every datetime conversion. It's really handy if you need other types of conversions.

Answer (score 7):

This will return just the time, not the date.

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 100), 7) AS time
```

For your table data:

```
select RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, tdate ,100), 7) AS [Time] from table
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code will return only time like 10:30 PM

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(getdate() AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS [Time]
```

Answer (score 2):

Get date of server

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))
```

or

If it is stored in the table

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), datename, 100), 7))
```

Result:

> 11:41AM

Answer (score 0):

```
ifnull(date_format(at.date_time,'%d/%m/%Y'),"") AS date_time,
ifnull(time_format(at.date_time ,'%h:%i:%s'),"") AS date_time
```

This is how a SQL procedure looks...(for separating date and time)..there is no need of a special column for time/date....

Note:if H instead of h it will show the "hour in 24 hour" format

Comment: Hi Arjun, if I'm not mistaking that looks like MySQL. The question is for SQL Server.